# Create object with arraylist and clear it without clearing the arraylist in the object

Tags: java, arraylist

How do I create an object with an `arraylist` and then when I clear the `arraylist` I want the value to still be inside the object.

```
for (int i = 0; i < attribute.getLength(); i++) {
    String current = attribute.item(i).getTextContent();
    if(current.equals("Identifier")){
        String hyperlink = list.get(count).hyperlink;
        String title = list.get(count).title;
        String identifier = list.get(count).identifier;
        ItemAndAttributeObject object = new ItemAndAttributeObject(hyperlink, identifier,  title, attributeList);
        objectList.add(object);
        count++;
        attributeList.clear();
    }
    else{
        attributeList.add(current);
    }
}
```

When I run this code all the `ItemAndAttributeObject` attributes are empty. How do I keep the value in the objects?

This is how my class, creating the objects looks like

```
public class ItemAndAttributeObject {
    String hyperlink;
    String identifier;
    String title;
    ArrayList<String> attributes;

    public ItemAndAttributeObject(String hyperlink, String identifier, String title, ArrayList<String> attributes) {
        this.hyperlink = hyperlink;
        this.identifier = identifier;
        this.title = title;
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }
}
```

I want is to create an object with an `arraylist` of values and then clear the array for the next iteration in the loop.

Comment: So you create some objects put them in an array list in some scope, clear the arraylist in that scope and want the objects to still be here? Why?? This question kind of smells like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

Don't keep using and clearing the same `ArrayList`.  Create a new `ArrayList` each time.